# Objective-C pass enum as parameter in other class?

Tags: objective-c, enums

This is simple question but I have search on Google and stackoverflow but I cant found an example.

I write enum in Account.h and define a method use this enum as parameter:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, httpMethod){
    GET = 0,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
};

//method definition
-(void) location:(httpMethod)httpMethod withLocation:(NSString *)location;
```

In other class implementation, I call this method

```
// I do not know how to pass the enum as parameter
[self.myAccount location:Account.httpMethod.PUT withLocation:string];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the enum value:

```
[self.myAccount location:PUT withLocation:string];
```

Comment: thank you I find this solution, but why my Xcode do not give me content assistant? I thought I could not pass "PUT" because Xcode do not give hints

Comment: It could happen if Xcode is indexing your project files. Wait until is finished and then close/reopen it